# How to express the properties of users who belog to multiple departments in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

In Active Directory the User entry can have several attributes such as title, department, manager, physicalDeliveryOfficeName which express a kind of user's belong, role, location.

If an user belongs to two different departments and acts as a different role in each department, how do you guys put those values into the user's attribute in Active Directory?

Example scenario

- Smith is a SR Account Executive in Sales Department and also acts as Marketing Specialist in Marketing Department.
- Sales Department is located in Los Angeles and Marketing Department is in San Francisco. Smith spends the time in one of those office half of a week.
  Smith reports to Johnson with Sales related and William with Marketing related.

title:SR Account Executive
department:Sales Department
physicalDeliveryOfficeName:Los Angeles
managedBy:Johnson

title:Marketing Specialist
department:Marketing Department
physicalDeliveryOfficeName:San Francisco
managedBy:William

Since those attribute is defined as single value in Active Directory Schema, do you extend new custom attributes schema that is allowed multi-value?

or

the user has only one value that he/she is involved more deeply with?.

or

You use a kind of people application that can host mult-ivalue rather than Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do whatever works for you. But this isn't a normal thing, so anything you do to try and display two roles on one account will mess up everything you do for reporting from Active Directory.

I suggest you create a second account (with its own mailbox) for him for the second role. This way, all values are single-value as you would usually expect.

He does not necessarily need to log into the second account. There are a couple ways you could set it up:

1. You can give his first account access to his second mailbox, and he can view each mailbox separately (if you use Outlook, both mailboxes can both be added).
2. If he doesn't like that, you can forward mail from the second mailbox to the first mailbox and configure Outlook to reply from the second email address for emails that were addressed to that second mailbox.

Besides that, you could just put both sets of information in the same fields, like title = "SR Account Executive / Marketing Specialist". But that is more likely to confuse anyone looking at it, and mess up any reporting from Active Directory that you do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it may be a good way for my case. Is there an attribute to tie first account and second one? I mean I want these account be recognized same account for searchers if I could. I think we have several ways to do that, for example adding particular string in displayName etc but I want to take more smart way if I have.

Comment: No, there is no attribute to identify it as the same account. If you store an employee ID, you could set that the same. But you might benefit from both accounts coming up in a search. They are two distinct jobs.